# Get an image file stored on a parse server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, parse-server

I have a web app using react-redux for the front end and parse server for the backend.

I wanted to know how could i get an image file stored in a column of a class on parse server?

I've checked something about Parse.File but i've found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the documentation here:

https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#files and particularly 
https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#retrieving-file-contents